# Facebook api PHP - Setting privacy of photo post to custom but shows "only me" instead of friend

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-tag

I am trying to set the privacy of a photo. I have tagged tester 1 and specify that I would like to share this photo with just tester 2.

I have the following code:

```
  $privacy = array(
    'value' => 'CUSTOM',
    'friends' => 'SOME_FRIENDS',
    'allow' => 'tester 2 id',
    );

$photo = (new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'PHOTO',
'/me/photos',
array (
    'source' => new CURLFile ($location.$name),
    'message' => ($caption),
    'privacy' => json_encode ($privacy),
 )

))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

//echo '<pre>' . print_r( $photo, 1) . '</pre>';
$photo_id = $photo['id'];
 echo $photo_id;

$tags = array( array( 'tag_uid' => $friend_id, 'x' => 0, 'y' => 0 ));

// call api to tag friend to photo, with json_encoded $tags
$tag = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'.$photo_id.'/tags', 
array(
'tags' => json_encode( $tags ) ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

I have no included the id of tester 2 but in my app, I have the id. When I run this, on my facebook the privacy shows that only I can see it - "only me" and whoever is tagged. For tester 1, it says the privacy setting is "custom".

I am not sure what the problem is. Why it says "only me" when I have specify "custom" and a friend id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right,

The privacy setting is based on that user's privacy settings.

[Click Here To See](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos)

```
Permissions

A user access token with `user_photos` permission is required to see all photos that person is tagged in or has uploaded.
```

So if `user 2` is tagged in a picture and also they own it, only `user 1` will show up cause they are the only one who accepted the `permission approval`.

In order for a friend to show up I believe they would have to accept your app by logging in and accepting the permissions you are requesting in your `array` `user_photos`

Also I believe there are settings on facebook that can let them not allow people to see what they are `tagged in`.

You can test this theory by going into your facebook app `developers.facebook.com @`
[Click Here](https://developers.facebook.com/)

go to your `app/roles` `Add Testers` . Then have them access your application and see if you can see if they are tagged in a photo now once they have accepted.

I am not sure what will happen, but this would be the appropriate way to test it.

Comment: I don't understand. So when I use the api/privacy setting to post a photo onto facebook, only people who are using my app can see the post? Also, I have already tested it using testers.. User 1 tagged user 2, and in the privacy allowed user 3 to see the photo, however user 3 can't see the photo still. When I don't specify the privacy, all users can see the post. Confused.